# PHP boolean: why `true == 'false'` is true?

Tags: php

Here is a sample code to show my question, When I doing my job I espial this,
But I could't find some article about this, so which one can help me resolve question? Let's see below PHP code.

```
<?php 
   $sFalse = 'false';
   if ($sFalse) {
     echo '1. true <br/>';}
   else {
     echo '1. false <br/>';
   }
   if (true == $sFalse) {
     echo '2. true <br/>';}
   else {
     echo '2. false <br/>';
   }
 ?>
```

this printout

```
1. true
2. true
```

I can't understand why both print true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `'false'` is not a false value, it is a string that contains something.

So when the comparison is made, `'false'` is equal to `true`.

A value is false if :

- it is false : `$val = false;`
- it is an empty string : `$val = "";`
- it is zero : `$val = 0;`
- it is null : `$val = null;`

See [comparisons documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php).

Answer (score 1):

That's because of the difference between strict and non-strict.

Have a look at the PHP docs of Booleans for some good examples and explanations:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php

Answer (score 0):

```
    //This is a String so its true in If condition
   $sTrue = 'false';
   if ($sTrue) {
     echo '1. true <br/>';}
   else {
     echo '1. false <br/>';
   }
   //And here you checking string with boolean so its always true
   if (true == $sTrue) {
     echo '2. true <br/>';}
   else {
     echo '2. false <br/>';
   }
```

You should use `===` for strict type check

`true === $sTrue` - It is false

Answer (score 0):

As you know an empty string `''` can be casted to boolean type `false`. But 'false ' is not an empty string so php can't cast 'false' into a boolean false. On the other hand expression `'false' == ''` is false in php.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 if conditions so they need to be considered separately.  This is an essential point, as each is it's own distinct operation that does not directly affect the other.

First we create a string `"false"` this is a string and not a boolean value.

```
$sFalse = 'false';
```

Then we ask (if's are questions we want to answer) is $sFalse true, and it's a string with content, which PHP considers true, so it triggers `echo '1. true <br/>';`

```
if ($sFalse) {
   echo '1. true <br/>';
}else {
   echo '1. false <br/>';
}
```

Next we again ask if `$sFalse` is true, and again it is (big surprise right)
so it again triggers `echo '2. true <br/>';`

```
if (true == $sFalse) {
   echo '2. true <br/>';
}else{
   echo '2. false <br/>';
}
```

Now this `if($sFalse)` and `if(true == $sFalse)` are equivalent in PHP, so basically you are asking the same exact question 2x.

So now that we know we are asking the same exact question, in two separate and distinct operations, is it any surprise they are the same?  If I give you a red ball, and I ask is the ball red, you say "Yes" if I ask again, is the ball red, what do you think the answer will be?

Now if you had instead asked `if(true === $sFalse)` with three `=` which is strict type checking, basically the type must match.  Then it would trigger the else because `'false'` is `true`, but it is not a boolean true.

If you had instead set the variable to false boolean `$sFalse = false;` then both else conditions would trigger (in either case `==` or `===`)

It's Unclear in your question what the expected output should be so I can not explain much more.