# How to change name of a variable using another variable

Tags: php, variables

Firstly, I wrote this code, but it's too long...

```
    if ($option1 == 'true')
        {
            echo "it works";
        }
    if ($option2 == 'true')
        {
            echo "it works";
        }
    if ($option3 == 'true')
        {
            echo "it works";
        }
    if ($option4 == 'true')
        {
            echo "it works";
        }
    if ($option5 == 'true')
        {
            echo "it works";
        }
    if ($option6 == 'true')
        {
            echo "it works";
        }
    if ($option7 == 'true')
        {
            echo "it works";
        }
```

So, I want to improve code and have something like this, but it doesn't work. I can't understand how to change the name of a variable of `if` inside the for.

Thanks for help.

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 7; $i++)
{
    if ($option($i) == "true")
        {
            echo "it works";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php 2) Learn to use arrays instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP boolean: why \`true == 'false'\` is true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48700737/php-boolean-why-true-false-is-true)

Answer (score 0):

Use curly braces to name a variable after a constructed string:

```php
if ( ${"option$i"} == true ) …
```

… but as stated in the comments, if what you want to do is INDEXING a collection of variables using a incremental number, you want to use regular arrays, especially if you plan to move to other languages (like C) that don't support this way of referencing.

PHP also supports associative arrays which enables you to use a string rather than a number as an index, which makes them key->value pair collections.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a feature called variable variables that you can use to dynamically reference variables based on string names. I wouldn't recommend using them because it leads to difficult to understand code later on.  https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php